# How should I respond to old questions that I find but don't fully answer what I'm looking for?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, best-practices

I seem to find a lot of older questions that address what I wish to ask (and seem to be answered) but do not completely clarify an answer to my question. I don't want to start a new one just to piggyback off of what I've found, since I often think that the original answer "suffices", but is still a concept that I do not understand.

Resurrecting the old post seems futile if the original poster/answerer are gone, and if no one else gets notified (I am not quite sure how things work in that aspect around here).

So should I start a new question referring to the old, or would it be better to comment on the old instead? Does commenting on older posts bring them to anyone's attention? (That is, besides the original posters and anyone to whom I'm directing comments.)

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16502/how-best-to-re-ask-a-question-that-wasnt-fully-answered

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'd done a quick search, but I'm too engrossed in trying to figure out my original issue that I'm searching for to dig through so many options. I appreciate it!

Comment: This seems related too: [Clarify an old answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4108). (And you might also check whether you will find something interesting [among the linked discussions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4108).)